# Generate a random integer array with repeating values in J

Tags: arrays, random, j

I want to generate a random array with repeating values. Something like this:

```
4 11 6 3 5 4 16 11 26 5 4
```

I know that the statement `12 ? 50` will generate a random integer array with 12 *unique* values in the range 0 to 49. How would I allow repeating values?

Also can J create random floating point arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the Roll (`?`) will give repeating values depends on the ratio of its arguments. If the repeatability requirement is optional, then just use Roll. If it is mandatory then first use the Roll to get unique values, and then dispense that values to get the length required.

J Vocabulary for Roll [says](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/query) how to get a random floating-point number:

```
   ? 0      NB. as a scalar
0.331228
   ] r=. 5 ?@$ 0  NB. as an array of shape x (which is 5 here)
0.331228 0.905526 0.71756 0.637666 0.486918
```

Then it may be scaled to the range desired, say, the open interval (3,26), via arithmetic operators:

```
   ] s=. 3 + (26-3) * r
10.6182 23.8271 19.5039 17.6663 14.1991
```

or via [Polynomial](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/pdot#dyadic) (`p.`):

```
   ] s=. (3 , 26-3) p. r
10.6182 23.8271 19.5039 17.6663 14.1991
```

And then it may be dispensed to the final length (say, 8):

```
   (8 ?@$ 5) { s
10.6182 14.1991 17.6663 10.6182 17.6663 17.6663 23.8271 19.5039
```

Answer (score 4):

NuVoc tells you in [?'s documentation](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/query#dyadic) under 'Use These Combinations':

```
   5 ?@$ 10
3 3 7 7 0
   5 ?@$ 10
6 7 6 6 9
```

This has the same effect but is more performant than

```
   ? 5 $ 10
6 1 1 8 9
   ? 5 $ 10
5 9 7 2 9
```

Which of course builds an array of five 10s and then applies ? to each of them to get a random number from 0..9, independently of the other results.

> And can J create floating point arrays.

Totally missed this question. Yes, you'd do this the same way as with any other kind of array.

```
   datatype 1 2 3
integer
   datatype 1.1 2.2 3.3
floating
```